# Moderators are taking action without acknowledging the users

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

I have seen moderators doing whatever they want in any chat-room, they take action or suspend users whenever they want without letting know the user know the reason for those actions.

Why is that so? *MODERATOR* should at least let know the reason why he has taken action against a user, so that will clear the confusion in user mind as well as this is a good way to deal with users here.

If I am wrong please rectify me.

Comment: I see you are now suspended from Stack Overflow for gaming the system - is that what you were talking about all the time??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a room, you have the ability to control it as you please.  In general, if you aren't allowed into a room due to the moderator, you are welcome to start your own room.

If the room you've been banned from appears to be a general purpose, public room, and you believe the moderator is excluding you for no good reason, you could appeal to the community (such as here) but again - they created the room, or the person who did gave them moderating power over it, so by default they own it.

Comment: how can i appeal to the community  regarding room moderator know me the procedures.

Comment: @Robinhood If you feel that the moderator is being abusive, you can post a message here with a link to the transcript showing the abuse, or describe the abuse, the room, and those involved.  The chat rooms are very, very lightly moderated, so don't expect any action unless the abuse you are experiencing is severe.

Answer (score 4):

That's the whole purpose of the room moderator: allowing people in and kicking people out.

If you think the moderator is rude or kicked people without good reason take screenshots of what he said and post the details here, the community will judge.

Comment: Can't see anything in your profile which means you're not suspended. So what exactly do you mean? What messages you get?

Comment: So you probably just got suspended from the chat - can't say why, I don't know what you said and to whom.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question here with what you told me and ask why - the edit will bump the question to the front page and hopefully some moderator will see and post reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is wrong. Let me explain the reason to you.

- **Chat-Room Suspenstion**

  - In chat room when other users flag your message which is not valid in public chat. When such thing happens you are suspended for half an hour or may be few hours. You can view the details by clicking the remaining time display to removal of suspension in the chat room's typing box.
- **User Suspension**

  - This happens when you perform some illegal activity on the site. For e.g. **Serial upvoting** found on your reputation, **[Low-Quality contribution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162551/robinhood)** on the site, **[cool-down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514945/manjotsingh?tab=summary)**, **[voting irregularities](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646806/robinhood)**, **[rule violations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186750/user1409213)** etc. For such kind of suspension moderators needs to check all the links of your activity. After this happens Moderator decides to suspend your account for certain amount of period which is minimum a week to maximum a year.

Morel is in both the cases moderator first check the history of the user and then after take the appropriate decision. In chat room suspension generally one moderator or automatic running script perform suspension, while in User suspension a group of moderators perform history checking, You can see these moderator's list when you login for the first time after the suspension. There you can see a textbox to communicate/feedback a message to moderator for your clarification.